# Accessing GKE internal LB IP from internet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

Any workaround to access `GKE internal load balancer IP` from Internet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to access to an internal IP from the Internet? you should create a tcp load balancer instead of an internal load balancer. Just remove this annotation:
networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"

In any case, you can always use a proxy (like HA proxy) and forward traffic to this internal IP.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I used Apache reverse proxy to access the Load balancer IP